# Scriptrunner Behaviours: How to set custom filed value only one time when screen shows

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-integration, automation-for-jira

Version - Behaviours with Jira v5.5.9.

I need to do simple thing - to set default value in field on the screen. It's worked perfectly via behaviour script server-side script. Although if user manually cleans value on the screen, behaviour set default field value again, so user can't select another value.

If I use initialiser script instead server-side script with this field or another, I will have different problem. If user doesn't fill all required fields, behaviour set default field value after validation error.

So I need to set  default field value only one time, when screen shows, and user must have opportunity to change it. Any options?

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.onresolve.jira.groovy.user.FieldBehaviours
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
@BaseScript FieldBehaviours fieldBehaviours

final String screenName = 'test'
if (fieldScreen.name == screenName) {
    def myfield = getFieldById(getFieldChanged())   
    if (myfield.getValue().toString().length() == 0) { 
        myfield.setFormValue("default")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this code only if the operation is "Create" by adding this code below: `if(actionName == "Create")`

Your code will be like this:

```
if((fieldScreen.name == screenName) && (actionName == "Create")) {
    //...
}
```